# MSGraph equivalent of MSOnline's StrongAuthenticationRequirement?

Tags: powershell

I have the following Windows PowerShell code, which enforces MFA on user creation:

```
        $st = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
        $st.RelyingParty = "*"
        $st.State = "Enforced"
        $sta = @($st)
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $sta | Out-Null
```

Since MSOnline is supposed to be deprecated, and isn't being updates for PowerShell Core, is there an equivalent of this code in MSGraph (or other modules) that does the same?

Comment: There's not currently an MS Graph method to enable per-user MFA

Answer (score 0):

There is a cmdlet map:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0

sel-msolUser gets replaced by update-mguser:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/update-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0&preserve-view=true

the module to install is microsoft.graph there you get the 'mg' cmdlets, docu:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.bookings/?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Comment: This is not helping. The `Update-MgUser` don't have a argument for `StrongAuthenticationRequirement`.